# find & download all smart contracts deployed?

Tags: tools

is there any existing tools that can find & download all smart contracts deployed on Ethereum blockchain, regardless they have source code or not?

if there is no such a tool, what is the best way to implement one? i suppose we can look at all the transactions sent to 0x0, but this requires access to a big full node?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any existing tools that can find & download all smart contracts deployed on Ethereum blockchain, regardless they have source code or not?

There is no such tool.

> if there is no such a tool, what is the best way to implement one? i suppose we can look at all the transactions sent to 0x0, but this requires access to a big full node?

If you want to find all contracts and their code, your only option is to run a debug trace (offered by both Parity and Geth) using an archival node on each tx throughout Ethereum's history, and look for calls invoking the `CREATE` op code.

Moreover, this will only give you the bytecode for each contract, not the source code. Ethereum does not store the source code, and you will either need to use a disassembler, which rarely produces good quality source code, or scrape other services such as Github to find the code to common contracts, or run a service similar to etherscan which allows users to submit their contract source to you.

Comment: I wonder if rather than setting up your own archival node, you could use [Google's new dataset on BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics). But ya, Raghav is totally right, results would just be byte code...

Comment: I'm not sure if that datasets lists op codes. It would miss contracts created via internal calls if it doesn't

Comment: So here is what I understand, is that correct? (1) Browse all the blocks from genesis, then look for transactions with "to" address of `0`, and get the transaction payload as contract bytecode (2) Somehow run this contract bytecode, and look for CREATE instruction, and extract the bytecode from input argument of CREATE as a new contract (3) Repeat step (2) with this new contract extracted from CREATE, because this contract can also create a new contract.

Comment: By "contracts created via internal calls", do you mean the CREATE instruction?

Comment: Correct. If you trace every transaction, you will cover both externally deployed contracts and contracts created by internal calls with just one iteration.